# активировать кнопку как-только начали вводить текст в EditText

Tags: android

при открытии активности кнопка неактивна. Как активировать кнопку как-только начали вводить текст в EditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          button.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы если текст очистили, снова кнопка стала недоступной?

Comment: На методе afterTextChange берите у editable длинну и если она равна 0 то делайте button.setEnabled(false)

Comment: спасибо помогло